# What is your recommended road-map to learn Julia from scratch?

Tags: julia

How can I learn Julia from scratch. I have decent programming knowledge in R and C.

Comment: SO is QA based community, please read "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)".

Answer (score 5):

I am newbie in Julia-Lang, and a bad English writer!, anyway, based on my few experiences in Julia, I recommend the following road map:

- Check julia-lang official [website](http://julialang.org/) specially documentation part [here](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/), download pdf version and read it carefully.
- Install latest release from official site (I know you have already done it).
- Define sample test projects for yourself and try to do them in Julia (very important).
- **Ask your real questions about Julia codding here.** There are many nice stackoverflow users, that are ready to answer your questions.
- You can always reach some tutorials using google (e.g check this one: http://www.learnxinyminutes.com/docs/julia/), but keep in your mind that Julia is an **open-source** language and there are some special sort of things about this kind of applications, thanks http://www.github.com anyone can easily find the maximum number of good codding practices by **git**, (take a look at http://pkg.julialang.org/).
- So learn how to `git` and use it to share your useful experiences and to collaborate with others.
- Another important point about open-source applications is that, there is not a company to warrant them, or creates training stuffs for users, so they must rely on their community. Thankfully Julia has a strong community that supports it. Check https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/julia-users.

Well come.

Comment: Nice answer! Another place to look is the [learning](http://julialang.org/learning/) section on the website, where a number of tutorials are listed including some video tutorials and recorded workshops (such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gQ1y5NUD_RI&list=PLP8iPy9hna6Sdx4soiGrSefrmOPdUWixM&index=3) from JuliaCon 2015).